# Load scripts based on post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

Is there a nice way to load a js file based on the post type being viewed?

I have a supplier which has a map on it but I only want the load the js when a single one is being viewed. I load the script in my functions.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hook onto a later action such as `template_redirect`, you should be able to check the query vars to determine if your specific post type is being viewed.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'example_callback' );

function example_callback() {
    if( is_single() && get_query_var('your-posttype') )
        wp_enqueue_script( .. your args .. );
}
```

Or alternatively like this...

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'example_callback' );

function example_callback() {
    if( is_single() && get_query_var('post_type') && 'your-type' == get_query_var('post_type') )
        wp_enqueue_script( .. your args .. );
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Though note, there are other actions you could also use and perform the same logic, two examples would be `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
add_action('admin_init','load_my_script');
function load_my_script() {
  global $typenow;
  if (empty($typenow) && !empty($_GET['post'])) {
    $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
    $typenow = $post->post_type;
  }
  if (!is_admin() && is_single() && $typenow=='your post type') {
    //load your script here
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: @Alex - care to explain what doesnt work? what does? is it on the frontend or backend?

Comment: It's in the themes functions file which needs to sort the front end out. Getting the post doesn't return anything: $post = get_post($_GET['post']);